# Why can't I enter privileged EXEC mode?

Tags: switch, packet-tracer

I created a network in Packet Tracer using 2 switches, 3 PCs and straight through cables.
[image]

I have to create the following configuration for both switches:

```
no ip domain-lookup

service password-encryption

enable secret class

banner motd #

Unauthorized access is strictly prohibited. #

line con 0

password cisco

login

logging synchronous

line vty 0 15

password cisco

logging synchronous

login

Exit
```

And now I can't enter privileged EXEC mode... I enter simple EXEC mode and type the password cisco to enter privileged EXEC mode and after 3 times I get the messege "bad secrets"...

[[image: This is what happens when I try to enter privileged EXEC mode1]

What should I do? Why does that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the secret to "**class**" right in the configuration, so that password is no longer "**cisco**".

Use the new secret that you are configuring.